# How can I create ActiveRecord for the following sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I create an ActiveRecord Query for the following Sql query

```
SELECT device1.*
FROM devices device1
WHERE device1.id = (SELECT MAX(device2.id)
                 FROM devices device2
                 WHERE device2.user_id = device1.user_id);
```

I have `Device` model with `user_id` column

I dont want to user `find_by_sql` because it returns `Array` instead `ActiveRecord Array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like:

```
Device.where(id: Device.select("MAX(id)").from('devices devices2').where("devices2.user_id = devices.user_id"))
```

which will produce:

```
SELECT "devices".*
FROM "devices"
WHERE "devices"."id" IN (
  SELECT MAX(id)
  FROM devices devices2
  WHERE (devices2.user_id = devices.user_id)
)
```